# How to properly use Go html/template precompiled?

Tags: go, go-html-template

Full source code: https://github.com/remoteworkerid/backendgolang/blob/feature/RWIDPF-13/server.go

My code works for DEV_MODE==true. But it doesn't for DEV_MODE==false.

PrecompileTemplate:

```
func precompileTemplate() {
    // Menggunakan template.ParseGlob untuk memuat semua file template
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("static/*.html"))
    templateNames := templates.Templates()
    fmt.Println("Nama-nama template yang terdaftar:")
    for _, t := range templateNames {
        fmt.Println(t.Name())
    }
}
```

HomeHandler:

```
    if devMode {
        tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("static/base.html", "static/daftar.html")
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base.html", data)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }

    } else {
        log.Println("Production code daftar")
        err = templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base.html", data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Ada error di daftar")
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }
```

My base.html excerpt:

```
<div id="content" class="p-5">
{{block "content" .}}
</div>
```

My daftar.html (full):

```
{{ define "content" }}
<h1>Daftar RWID</h1>
{{ end }}
```

How do you render a precompiled template for subtemplate case? I kinda expecting the ExecuteTemplate will accept three parameter: base, sub and data. But as its' only one.. I am guessing `daftar.html` (a subtemplate). But, in daftar.html I didn't mention the superclass..

Comment: Please provide a complete, runnable, minimal reproducible example so we can actually test and verify: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use base template file for golang html/template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617949/how-to-use-base-template-file-for-golang-html-template). Try something like `templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base.html", map[string]string{"content": "signup.html"})`

Comment: Hmm. Probably. The different is it call the base and pass the subtemplate as data. Will check!

Comment: @swdev your `signup.html` is really just a `define` block; this will not output anything (you need to call `{{template "signup.html"}}` to execute the block you defined; and that happens in `base.html`). If your aim is to do something different then you will need to explain this.

Comment: added repo here: https://github.com/remoteworkerid/backendgolang/blob/feature/RWIDPF-13/server.go